# :: и -> PHP

Tags: php, классы, ооп

Вот почему код

```
Some_class::a
```

Работает, а код

```
Some_class->a
```

Выдает ошибку? В чем вообще отличие **::** от **->**?

Answer (score 6):

для статических методов в классе **::**

для методов созданного объекта **->**

Answer (score 5):

[Оператор разрешения области видимости (::)](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

Статические методы удобно использовать там, где для его работы не требуется создание экземпляра класса.

Со static:

```
$s = str::hash($s);
```

Без static:

```
$str = new str();
$s = $str->hash($s);
```

Статическое свойство - общее для всех экземпляров класса (точнее ни одному из них не принадлежит). Полезно, если вы создаете объекты в разных местах программы, но отовсюду вам нужен доступ к общей переменной. Частный случай - реализация синглетона, когда вам нужен один и тот же экземпляр в разных местах программы (статик-свойство - сам объект):

```
class db {
   protected static $instance;

   private function __construct() {}
   private function __clone() {}
   private function __wakeup() {}
   public static function get() {
       if (is_null(self::$instance)) self::$instance = new db;
       return self::$instance;
   }
   public function query() {}
}
db::get()->query();
```

***ЗЫЖ*** Если сделать:

```
$someclass = new Some_class();
$someclass->a;
```

то не будет выводить ошибку :) зависит от того что там в классе.

Answer (score 4):

Если создан объект(экземпляр класса), то ->, :: - обращение **только** к статическим членам класса, то есть, объявленным static function func(){} или static $var.

Comment: Ну ещё и к константам :)